# 'made of' or 'made from' or both when describing a drink?

Tags: grammar

> Beer made of yeast grown in a lab
>
> Beer made from yeast grown in a lab

I would use 'made from', but ChatGPT says 'made of' is also grammatical, but knowing ChatGPT is terrible at detecting grammar error, I just wanted to double check to make sure both were considered correct.

When describing a table, I know for a fact "made of wood" is more appropriate than "made from wood", but I also know that both are correct. In this case, I am not sure if both can be said to be grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both grammatical, but the second is better semantically.

Take the 'wood' example:
A sculpture might be made *of* wood, but paper is made *from* wood.

In the same way beer is not made of yeast, because yeast is just one of its ingredients.